# mysql find difference from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I need to find out how many people from our free samples table became customers in our customers table. Here is what I have for the 2 tables:

```
SELECT free_samples.id, 
free_samples.first_name, 
free_samples.last_name, 
free_samples.address, 
free_samples.city, 
free_samples.state, 
free_samples.zip
FROM free_samples
```

and then the customers table

```
SELECT customers.id, 
customers.firstName, 
customers.lastName, 
customers.address, 
customers.city, 
customers.state, 
customers.zip
FROM customers
```

Note that the id's are not the same so that makes it difficult to match. So again, I need to know how many free sample requests actually became customers. Is there a way in with a query to identify this?

Thank you

Comment: So you just want to `JOIN` the tables on everything other than id?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `INNER JOIN` to get the results that have matches in both tables (i.e. people that were in `free_samples` AND made it to `customers`):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM customers a
    INNER JOIN free_samples b
        ON
            a.firstname=b.firstname
            AND a.city=b.city
            AND a.state=b.state
            AND a.zip=b.zip
            AND a.address=b.address
            AND a.lastname=b.lastname
```

NOTE: It's considered bad practice to `SELECT *`, I just wasn't sure exactly what data you'd need to pull.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM free_samples AS fs, customers AS c 
    WHERE fs.first_name = c.first_name
      AND fs.last_name = c.last_name
      AND fs.address = c.address
      AND fs.city = c.city
      AND fs.state = c.state
      AND fs.zip = c.zip;
```

The query is pretty simple, but I think this is not a good way to do achieve your purpose.

Just add a new column 'free_samples_id' on 'customers' table to keep the id of 'free_samples' table. And record the id into the 'customers' table when a free user register as a customer.

Comment: +1, COUNT(*) would give "how many" as the author requested.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

I never did learn the difference between LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN but I think this looks like a great situation to use it :P

Edit: Just seen the comment above me, and he's right. This code would actually get you customers who haven't converted their free sample into a membership. It's the exact opposite of what you wanted, but I'll leave it on the off-chance someone else may find it useful some time :)

=================

Basically you want something like

```
    SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, c.address, c.city, c.state, c.zip
      FROM customers c
 LEFT JOIN free_samples fs
        ON c.first_name = fs.first_name
       AND c.last_name = fs.last_name
       AND c.zip = fs.zip
```

You may need to change `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`, but I think one of those two should work. Someone else will come along and explain which one it should be, and why, I'm sure :)

If you want to compare any other fields, just add them to the bottom of the `JOIN`. It's important to note that the `AND c.zip = fs.zip` and so on aren't in the `WHERE` clause, they're conditions on the `JOIN`

Comment: `JOIN`s can definitely be confusing.  He'll want to use `INNER JOIN` to gte the matches from both.  `LEFT` would get everything from `customers` regardless of matches in `free_samples`

Comment: Agreed :) I tend to find `INNER JOIN` pretty much covers all of what I ever want to do, and once in a blue moon I'll go spend some Googling and refresh my memory on LEFT/RIGHT and then later on find a better way to do it without the LEFT/RIGHT join :P

Comment: Haha, Agreed - `INNER JOIN` usually does the trick.  I actually just had a problem that `LEFT JOIN` fixed though =)